# Why must triangle inscribed in circle have a right angle?

Tags: geometry

[image]

> > You should also notice that since $CP$ is the diameter of the circle, angle $CBP$ is a right angle.

says the solution to this question. But what is the reasoning or proof behind the claim that the angle opposite the diameter ($\angle CBP$)  must be a right angle?

I started to draw it out to gain some intuition, but I only got about as far showing that drawing a line from the center $O$  to the vertex of $CBP$ splits the inscribed triangle into two, where $\angle BOC + \angle BOP = \pi$. I'm not sure if that will lead to a proof, or whether this is more easily shown with e.g. the Law of Sines.

See also:

- [Praxis II practice for mathematics (source of this questions)](http://www.ets.org/Media/Tests/PRAXIS/pdf/0061.pdf)
- [angle of inscribed triangle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/454107/angle-of-inscribed-triangle)
- [inscribed triangle with circle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/336295/inscribed-triangle-with-circle?rq=1)

Comment: This is Thales' theorem.

Comment: There are various proofs here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thales'_theorem

Comment: The first proof on the Wikipedia page (linked in Mark Bennet's comment) does indeed start by drawing a line from the center of the circle to the opposite angle.

Comment: If what you say that book says is accurate, then that book is dead wrong. WHat is right is that $\,\angle CBP=90^\circ\,$ since this is an inscribed angle subtending a diameter (or an arc half the circle). We also have that $\,\angle APC=90^\circ\;$ as this is the angle formed by a tangent and a raidus at the tangency point.

Comment: @DonAntonio please check the [linked PDF](http://www.ets.org/Media/Tests/PRAXIS/pdf/0061.pdf) on page 12 ; have I misinterpreted it?

Comment: I think I see now what happened: apparently you have a typo there, @Trevor, since both in that link's answers and in your own post, there appears $\,\angle CBP\;$ , yet the *first* time you wrote $\,\angle CPB\;$ ...In fact what you have there is that $\;PB\;$ is the height to the hypothenuse $\;AC\;$ in the straight- angled triangle $\,\Delta ACP\;$ and we know such a height divides the original triangle in two smaller one which are similar to each other **and** also to the original triangle.

Comment: **Hint:** (for original question) from the knowledge that $\angle PBC$ is a right angle $\triangle ACP$,  $\triangle APB$ and  $\triangle PBC$ are similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

In the diagram above $A$ is the centre of the circle and $CB$ is thus the diameter. Point $D$ is an arbitrary point in the circumference.

In $\triangle ACD$ $\angle CDA = \alpha$ since $AC = AD$

Thus

$$2 \cdot \alpha + \theta = 180 ^\circ$$

In $\triangle ADB$ $\angle ADB = \beta$ since $AB = AD$

Thus

$$2 \cdot \beta + (180^\circ - \theta) = 180 ^\circ$$

Add both these together

$$2 \cdot \alpha + 2 \cdot \beta + 180 ^\circ = 360 ^\circ$$

Which we can easily rearrange to show:

$$ \alpha + \beta = 90 ^\circ $$

We have thus proved $\angle CDB$ is a right angle as required.

Comment: Of course, you don't need to mention $\theta$.  The picture shows straight away that the sum of the internal angles of $BCD$ is $2\alpha+2\beta$, whence $\alpha+\beta$ is 90 degrees, as required.