# Geometric proof that angle does not exceed $90^\circ$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Problem: In rectangle $ABCD$, $BC=2AB$. Point $E$ is arbitrary point on $BC$. Prove that $\angle AED \le 90^\circ$.

I can show it using trig.

Let $CE=x$ then $$\cos \angle AED =\frac{AB^2+(2AB-x)^2+AB^2+x^2-4AB^2}{2 \cdot AE \cdot DE}=\frac{2AB^2-4AB\cdot x+2x^2}{2 \cdot AE \cdot DE}=\frac{(AB-x)^2}{AE \cdot DE} \ge0$$

However, I struggle to provide a geometric proof. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: How about using the circle with diameter $AD$ and then inscribed angles?

Comment: There is probably a way to use the fact that the area of triangle $AED$ is constant to show that $\angle AED$ must be less than or equal to 90, but I couldn't think of an obvious one without getting into trigonometry and pythagoras.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Construct a circle with diameter $AD$. Let the circle intersect $DE$ at point $F$. Then [$\angle AFD$ is right](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/474875/215011).

> If $F=E$ then $\angle AED=90$; if $F\ne E$ then $\triangle AFE$ is a right triangle with $\angle AFE=90$, hence the remaining angles of $\triangle AFE$ must be less than $90$. In particular $\angle AED<90$.

Comment: Isn't the problem here more or less equivalent with the claim that the circle actually intersects the segment DE? In other words, where did you use that $BC=2AB$?

Comment: @StinkingBishop I suppose the result holds even if $BC< 2AB$. Angle $ADE$ is less than 90 so segment $DE$ intersects the circle as long as $BC\le 2AB$; else the segment needs to be extended to intersect the circle at $F$. Perhaps this requires proof, depending on the level of rigor required.

Comment: But ... angle $\angle ADE<90^\circ$ even when $BC>2AB$, so how does your argument work then?

Comment: That was my point: the argument doesn't work when $BC>2AB$. When $BC>2AB$, then $F$ is outside the segment $DE$, so $\angle AED$ is not part of the triangle $\triangle AFE$.

Answer (score 0):

COMMENT.-In the attached figure, by the secants theorem,

$\angle{AED}=\dfrac{\angle{AOD}-\angle{FOG}}{2}\lt\dfrac{\pi}{2}-\dfrac{\angle{FOG}}{2}\lt 90^{\circ}$ when $E$ is not the tangency point $T$ in $BC$ side.

[image]

Comment: I think this could be simplified very considerably using the fact that AFD is a right angle, and AED must be less than or equal to AFD, as suggested in the comment under the question.

Comment: My main motivation for being a member of $MSE$ is to help beginners with something I know.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your knowledge Piquito.